# Elasticsearch conditional sorting by different fields (some fields can be empty)

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, conditional-statements

I have objects like this:

{
subStatus: {
updatedAt: 3
},
statusUpdatedAt: 1
},

{
subStatus: null,
statusUpdatedAt: 2
}

I need to sort the objects conditionally as follows:
relative to the subStatus.updatedAt field if the subStatus field exists,
or relative to the statusUpdatedAt field if the subStatus field does not exist

If both fields are absent, objects should be sorted to the end of the list

I used the following query:

```
    "sort": {

      "_script": {

        "type": "number",

        "order": "asc",

        "script": {

          "lang": "painless",

          "source": "if(doc['subStatus'].value != null) { return doc['subStatus.updatedAt'].value } else { return doc['statusUpdatedAt'].value }"

          }

      }

    }
```

But I get an Error: "No field found for [subStatus] in mapping with types []"

Could you advise me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try check by "size".

```
POST idx_fields/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"subStatus": { "updatedAt": 3 }, "statusUpdatedAt": 1 }
{"index":{}}
{"subStatus": null, "statusUpdatedAt": 2 }

GET idx_fields/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
          "source": "if(doc['subStatus.updatedAt'].size() > 0) { return doc['subStatus.updatedAt'].value } else { return doc['statusUpdatedAt'].value }"
      }
    }
  }
}
```